# Magento : Product Import to 1.9.3

Tags: magento2, product, importexport, magento1.9.3

We have magento website which is  in version2. We are developing a website which is in  version to 1.9.3. Can we export product data from admin panel of magento 2 and directly export to 1.9.3 site?

Comment: can anybody please help me it is eating my brain.I have exported all the products.the products attribute field in magento 2 and magento 1 is different

Comment: somebody please reply

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you can not export products from Magento 2 and directly import into Magento 1.x.

**Reason:** Magento 2 puts all custom attribute values under 1 column (**`additional_attributes`**) and saves attribute values in following format:

```
attribue_code1=value1,attribue_code2=value2,attribue_code3=value3..
```

While in Magento 1.x, each attribute is placed in individual column in csv file.

So you will need to add some efforts to convert Magento 2.x compatible csv file to Magento 1.x compatible format.

Please let me know if you have any other query.

Comment: yes this is the biggest problem we are facing  because we have more than 40,000 products and lots of attributes also.I did a fresh installation again.Can you tell me the steps what I should do to get out this please

Comment: If you are developer then you can read **`additional_attributes`** Magento 2.x compatible csv programatically, explode labels and values as pair and then rewrite csv with these columns.
Else it would be manual and time taking process.

Comment: is there any way that i can import directly from table to table?

Comment: No, there are tools which can migrate data from Magento 1.x to Magento 2.x, but for reverse case there is no tool available. Further the structure of tables has been changed in both versions, so I don't think that copying data from table to table would help.

Comment: thank you for suggestions..I wrote a php function for converting compatible to 1.9.3

Comment: Great. If your code works well, you can post generalised function as answer so that others can also get benefit from this community.